# Not able to find Xamarin.iOS Build Host on Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

After I installed Xamarin Studio v5.10 (build 871) on my Mac (OS X Yosemite v10.10.5), I can't find the `Xamarin.iOS Build Host`, even when using Spotlight. I want to pair Visual Studio with my Mac development machine. I found an answer on the Xamarin forums:

> I was having the same issue on my Mac and was able to resolve the
>   issue by deleting the following directories/folders and reinstalling.
>
> /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app /Developer/MonoTouch
>   /Developer/MonoAndroid /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> Thx, Leland

I performed these steps and have uninstalled Xamarin on the Mac and then reinstalled, but this hasn't helped. What can the problem be and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xamarin.iOS Build host has [evolved](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/xamarin-mac-agent/) into the Build Agent.

You now don't have to start a separate application to be able to connect to your Mac and compile your iOS apps.

Here's how to do it;

1. Enable Remote login on you Mac.
   With Spotlight search for `Remote Login` and tick the Remote Login box on the left side.
   Select which users or user groups can connect.

[image: Spotlight] [image: Enable Remote Login]

2. Go to your Visual Studio and find the new icon, click it

[image: Connect icon]

3. Find your host, it's probably just one and click connect. Enter your credentials (if you need to) and wait for the chain icon to appear on the right of the selected host.

[image: Select host]

From now own it should connect automagically. Just wait for the screen in the Visual Studio toolbar icon to turn green.

For more info check the [Xamarin documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/xamarin-mac-agent/).
Also when you're connecting this way for the first time on an existing Xamarin project be sure to do a clean and rebuild to avoid errors.

Answer (score 4):

OS-X `Build Host` has become OS-X `Build Agent`:

> Overview
>
> The Xamarin Mac Agent provides a way for Visual Studio
>   developers writing Xamarin.iOS apps to connect to a Mac effortlessly
>   to control the building, deployment, and running of apps. Visual
>   Studio connects to the Mac over SSH, which provides several benefits,
>   including:

Ref: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/xamarin-mac-agent/

Comment: Yes I activated the 'remote login' but I can't also not find `Build Agent` and pair VS with Mac.

Comment: There is no more 'pairing' using the old-style "XXXX" number, review the linked document on how the connections are established